# sunspot and rspec test failing as solr doesn't find any results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, rspec

I'm testing with Rspec my sunspot solr configuration.

I have:

```
  before(:each) do
    @company = create :company
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all companies as @companies" do
      get :index, {}, valid_session
      expect(assigns(:companies)).to eq([@company])
    end
  end
```

and my index controller:

```
  def index
    @search = Company.search do
      fulltext params[:search] 
    end
    @companies = @search.results
  end
```

the test fails with:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:companies)).to eq([@company])

   expected: [#<Company id: 613, name: "company 1", description: "description company 1", size: nil, company_link: "www.company1.com", created_at: "2015-04-13 12:52:56", updated_at: "2015-04-13 12:52:56">]
        got: []
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding to my factory_girl factory

```
 after(:create) { Company.reindex }
```

fixed the issue, Solr now reindexes everything after each creation so that the index is always consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have RSpec's `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`. In which case, you can add the following to the factory you want to index:

```
after(:create) { |c| c.index! }
```

Ref: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/182